# Pandas: convert date in month to the 1st day of next month

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

I am wondering if there are any efficient methods or one-liner that, given a pandas DatetimeIndex *date1*, return a DatetimeIndex *date2* that is the first day of the next month?

For example, if *date1* is '2011-09-30' then *date2* is '2011-10-01'?

I have tried this one liner

```
df.index.to_period("M").to_timestamp('M')
```

But this seems only able to return the "last day of the same month". Is it possible to do some datetime arithmetic here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `pd.offsets.MonthBegin()`

```
In [261]: d = pd.to_datetime(['2011-09-30', '2012-02-28'])

In [262]: d
Out[262]: DatetimeIndex(['2011-09-30', '2012-02-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [263]: d + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
Out[263]: DatetimeIndex(['2011-10-01', '2012-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You'll find a lot of examples in the [official Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets)

Comment: @MaxU Amazing. This possibly saves me hours. Yes I am new to Python and just skipped that part of the manual because I didn't quite understand. Thanks for providing the resources to more examples!

Comment: In pandas version 1.2.5 the `pd.offsets` has been changed to `pd.tseries.offsets`. So the changed command should be in this case `d+ pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(1)`.