# Modify date in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I read some data from a csv file and would like to convert all dates to the beginning of the month and then plot the data. I know how to manipulate a `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex` object, thanks to this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636265), but I do not know how to apply this to my `DataFrame` object. Reason is that I want to make a nice plot where the data is aligned.

Here is the csv file:

```
Date,Type,Value
2019-02-18,data1,4255
2019-02-21,data2,4155
2019-03-15,data1,4007
2019-03-07,data2,2255
2019-04-16,data1,3498
2019-04-12,data2,4275
2019-05-17,data1,2814
2019-05-11,data2,3255
```

and here my code for extracting the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

read_data = pd.read_csv('example.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
read_data2 = read_data[['Type','Value']]
data1 = read_data2[(read_data2['Type']=='data1')]
data2 = read_data2[(read_data2['Type']=='data2')]
ax = data1.plot(label='data1', y='Value', marker='x')
data2.plot(ax=ax, label='data2', y='Value', marker='x')
plt.show()
```

data1 looks as follows:

```
             Type  Value
Date                    
2019-02-18  data1   4255
2019-03-15  data1   4007
2019-04-16  data1   3498
2019-05-17  data1   2814
```

but I want it to look like

```
             Type  Value
Date                    
2019-02-01  data1   4255
2019-03-01  data1   4007
2019-04-01  data1   3498
2019-05-01  data1   2814
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you have one data point per month, then

```
df.resample('1M', label='left').first()  # end of month
df.resample('MS', label='left').first()  # beginning of month
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I do have exactly one data point per month or one data point every other month (use '2M' instead), so your answer is almost perfect. However, I get `2019-01-31` instead of `2019-02-01`. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Does not change anything, regardless of the combination of `label` and `closed`.

Comment: @Hannebambel try `convention="start"` or `convention="end"`

Comment: that does not help either. However, I found the solution: use `MS` instead of `M`. `MS` will sample to month start, whereas `M` samples to month end. Found it in the documention: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hannebambel One lives and learns! Thanks for figuring it out!

Comment: I modified your example to include the solution and accepted the answer. Hope you don't mind.