# How to change the day in datetime, to the first day of the current month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
          date     USDBRL
0   1994-01-31   458.6600
1   1994-02-28   637.4500
2   1994-03-30   913.3450
3   1994-04-29  1302.2800
4   1994-05-31  1875.2700
..         ...        ...
317 2020-06-30     5.4760
318 2020-07-31     5.2033
319 2020-08-31     5.4713
320 2020-09-30     5.6407
321 2020-10-09     5.5393
```

I would like to change all `date` values to the first day of the month.

I tried this:

```
df['date'] = datetime(df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month, 1)
```

but I'm getting syntax error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `pandas.offsets.MonthBegin` to set the day to the beginning of the month.
- Also [Pandas: convert date in month to the 1st day of next month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636171)
- [pandas User Guide: Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)
- [pandas: Date offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html)

  - [MonthBegin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html#monthbegin)
- `method 1` sets the day to the beginning of the month, but if the day is already the 1st, then the date is set to the first of the previous month.
- `method 2` first sets the date to the end of the month, then to the first of the month.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.Timestamp('1994-01-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('1994-02-28 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('1994-03-30 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('1994-04-29 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('1994-05-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-01-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-03-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-04-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-05-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-05-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-07-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-08-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-10-09 00:00:00')]})

# method 1
df['m1'] = df.date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

# method 2
df['m2'] = df.date - pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

[image]

- As noted by [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz) in a comment, there can be issues with `method 1`, if the day of the month is already the first.

  - At his suggestion, is a more robust solution, `method 2`, which accounts for days on the 1st.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.to_datetime` can assemble a datetime from a DataFrame with standard column names `'year'`, `'month'` and `'day`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='30D', periods=6)})

df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'day': 1, 
                                              'month': df['date'].dt.month, 
                                              'year': df['date'].dt.year},
                                              index=df.index))
```

---

```
        date   new_date
0 2010-01-01 2010-01-01
1 2010-01-31 2010-01-01
2 2010-03-02 2010-03-01
3 2010-04-01 2010-04-01
4 2010-05-01 2010-05-01
5 2010-05-31 2010-05-01
```