# Pandas dataframe timedelta is giving exceptions

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to get the next month first date based on billDate in a dataframe.

I did this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
dt = pd.to_datetime('15/4/2019', errors='coerce')
print(dt)
print((dt.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1))
```

It is working perfectly, and the output is :

```
2019-04-15 00:00:00
2019-05-01 00:00:00
```

Now, I am applying same logic in my dataframe in the below code

```
df[comNewColName] = (pd.to_datetime(df['billDate'], errors='coerce').replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)
```

But I am getting error like this:

```
---> 69                 df[comNewColName] = (pd.to_datetime(df['billDate'], errors='coerce').replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)
     70                 '''print(df[['billDate']])'''
     71                 '''df = df.assign(Product=lambda x: (x['Field_1'] * x['Field_2'] * x['Field_3']))'''
```

> TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'day'

Comment: You're calling [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), not `datetime.datetime.replace` or `pandas.Timestamp.replace`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: convert date in month to the 1st day of next month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636171/pandas-convert-date-in-month-to-the-1st-day-of-next-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_period.html) for month periods, add `1` for next month and then convert back to datetimes by [`Series.dt.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html):

```
print (df)
    billDate
0  15/4/2019
1  30/4/2019
2  15/8/2019

df['billDate'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['billDate'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
                   .dt.to_period('m')
                   .add(1)
                   .dt.to_timestamp())
print (df)
    billDate
0 2019-05-01
1 2019-05-01
2 2019-09-01
```

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly working. but logic is complex. that logic should appear like a pseudo code. Then I have to place that expression in my json. My BA team also able to understand.